# leaving someone + adjective

Tags: phrase-usage

Please take a look at these two sentences:

1. The teacher yelled at Finn, leaving him sad.
2. The teacher yelled at Finn and walked away, leaving him sad.

Can the phrase "leaving someone + adjective" be used in the first sentence even though the teacher doesn't walk away from him?

Comment: Why should it make any difference whether the teacher walked away (or not) after yelling at him? It wasn't the walking away that left him sad.

Comment: @RonaldSole because walking away from someone is also "leaving" them, with the more common meaning of "leave".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because "leaving someone sad" is a separate meaning of "leave" than the one in "leaving someone", or "leaving someone behind". In "leave behind", "leave" has to do with going away from. In your examples of "leave sad", "leave" does not mean going away from, it means "causing to be".

For some more examples and detail, see meanings 4 and 5 on the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/leave_1?q=leave)